# Subquery in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

So I have an Olympic database, the basic layout is that there's a competitors table with competitornum, givenname, and familyname (other columns aren't necessary for this)
There's also a results table with competitornum, and place (between 1 and 8).

I'm trying to get the givenname and familyname and total number of gold, silver, and bronze medals (place = 1, 2 or 3)

Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT c.Givenname, c.Familyname, places AS TotalPlaces
FROM Competitors c,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) as places 
         FROM Results r, Competitors c 
         WHERE r.Competitornum = c.Competitornum
         AND r.Place > 0
         AND r.Place < 4) q
```

However it returns everyone's name, and the same total places (which happens to be 78). e.g.

```
John Smith 78
Cassandra Jane 78
Bob Turner 78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your query is conducting `CROSS JOIN` producing caertesian product.

When using aggregate function (*count, max, min,...*), the records should be group by non-aggregated column. Try this,

```
SELECT c.Givenname, c.Familyname, COUNT(r.places) AS TotalPlaces
FROM Competitors c INNER JOIN Results r
        ON r.Competitornum = c.Competitornum
WHERE r.place IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY c.Givenname, c.Familyname
```

Comment: @GiantofaLannister so what's the diffrerence between `IN (1,2,3)` and `BETWEEN 0 AND 4`?

Comment: In case the OP wishes to change the range?

Comment: @GiantofaLannister fair enough.

Comment: I probably should've included this in the post, but I'm supposed to assume that the names won't always be different, e.g. there could be competitors with the same name. But your query uses competitornum to join right, so it should be okay?

Comment: @CoreyThompson yes, i guess you competitor number is unique right?

Comment: Yeah competitornum is unique, the names aren't though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JohnWoo I'm going to have to re-ask this question because I realised I needed a lot more, and I think your answer will probably have to change a lot and I can't figure it out... Lol. I'll post the link here? :)

Comment: @CoreyThompson sure you can update this question since it has not been completely answered.

Comment: Whoops, I already reasked it..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361614/sql-subqueries-for-top-result